# blast search against UNIPROT

Tags: bioinformatics, blast

I would like to ask how i can search in blast against UNIPROT (TREMBL PLUS SWISSPROT) for a selected organism. In the BLAST site there is no option about UNIPROT(only Swissprot), and in the uniprot site i cannot limit the results only in one organism(E.COLI).
THANKS A LOT!!!

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! Please take the [tour] and then go through the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site. In particular, this question seems like it might be a better fit for [Bioinformatics.SE]. Thanks! 

Comment: thank you and i am sorry!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can blast for E.coli proteins only using [Uniprot](https://www.uniprot.org/blast/). Firstly, you restrict the search to the "target database" UniprotKB...Bacteria. After performing the blast search, you can further restrict your search results to include only hits for one "Popular organism", e.g. "Escherichia".

Comment: thank you so much!!

Comment: @marilu Can you please mark my answer as correct?

Comment: is it ok?i think i did it

Comment: @marilu Yep, thank you!